# Dymanically bundle css files that come with user controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundle

I'm using asp.net 4.5 webform.

I have some custom controls and user contrls, which need css/js files to work together.

For example `SsnValidator.cs` introduces `SsnValidator.css`. `AutoCompleteDropDown.cs` introduces `AutoCompleteDropDown.css`. `ColorPicker.vb` introduces `ColorPicker.css`.

Currently I introduce css file in this way:

```
HtmlGenericControl styleLink = this.Page.Header.FindControl<HtmlGenericControl>("SsnValidatorStyle");
if (styleLink == null) {
    styleLink = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
    styleLink.Attributes.Add("href", CScriptUtils.GetResourceURL("/styles/SsnValidator.css"));
    styleLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
    styleLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
    styleLink.ID = "SsnValidatorStyle";
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(styleLink);
}
```

Now I find bundling can reduce the number of request. I think it may be useful to use it.

For example, if page a has `SsnValidator`, `AutoCompleteDropDown`, and `ColorPicker`, the three css files introduced should be somehow bundled together.

If page b has `SsnValidator` and `ColorPicker`, the two css files should be bundled together.

How can I achieve that? Is it desired to bundle these files?

Comment: Why would you want to do that???!? It makes much more sense to have these "componentized" as they are. Otherwise you're killing the cache mechanism.

Comment: @Amit Bundling can reduce the number of requests. If I have 10 controls which introduced 10 css files. Bundling can reduce requests from 10 to 1. Isn't it useful?  I revised my question. If you oppose bundling these files, feel free to post an answer.

Comment: I think that is opinion based, and I expressed my opinion. You shouldn't be asking about opinions though.

Comment: No, it's not useful if you have 20 pages with different combinations of bundles. That means each pages has to load a different bundle instead of using already cached resources. Either bundle the whole set, or don't do it at all.